# Input value from a specialized controller isn't being sent back to the main controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building an application that's making use of Angular UI Bootstrap's datepicker in several spots. I've included some other enhancements to this, such as validation styling, and wanted to propagate it everywhere so I put it in a directive.

```
app.controller('DateController', function () {

    var vm = this;

    vm.status = {
        opened: false
    };

    vm.open = open;

    function open($event) {
        vm.status.opened = true;
    }
});

app.directive('customDatePicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            bindingProperty: '=',
            minDate: '=',
            maxDate: '=',
            maxMode: '=',
            format: '=',
            isRequired: '=',
            form: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "/Scripts/SharedAngular/Templates/datePicker.html"
    };
});
```

With the template URL code looking like:

```
<div ng-controller="DateController as datePicker">
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="{{ name }}_datePicker" name="{{ name }}_datePicker" class="form-control" max-mode="maxMode" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="bindingProperty" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" ng-required="isRequired" close-text="Close" is-open="datePicker.status.opened" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="datePicker.open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="form.{{ name }}_datePicker.$invalid && form.{{ name }}_datePicker.$dirty" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign form-control-feedback datepicker-error-icon"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm including this directive in a couple places. It is placed on a page within the scope of a different controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <custom-date-picker name="'somePrefix'" form="myForm" binding-property="ctrl.date" max-mode="'month'" max-date="ctrl.currentDate" format="'yyyy/MM/dd'" is-required="true"></custom-date-picker>
</div>
```

So, I want to take a property from `myController` and two-way bind it to the directive's date picker. However, what ends up actually happening is that the current value for `ctrl.date` property is passed to the datepicker, but any changes to that value that happen in the directive are not sent back. So, it seems that `myController` and `DateController` only pass the value one-way, and only when the directive is loaded onto the page. To be clear, the directive doesn't seem to be the source of my issue, since putting the HTML code from the template directly onto my page results in the same behavior. So, it appears that the issue is specifically due to the use of two different controllers.

Previously, I was using ng-model both in the template code and the directive on my primary page. Neither option seems to work. I'm open to any ideas on how to get the input from my directive to be sent back to the `myController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to ditch the DateController entirely. I put my expressions directly into the template elements via `ng-click` and `ng-init`. The input creates a property called opened and uses `ng-init` initializes it to false. It then uses that property for the `is-open` attribute of the datepicker. Then the button just uses `ng-click="opened=true"`. Definitely simplifies things and removes the nesting of controllers.

Directive:

```
app.directive('customDatePicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            bindingProperty: '=ngModel',
            minDate: '=',
            maxDate: '=',
            maxMode: '=',
            format: '=',
            isRequired: '=',
            form: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: "/Scripts/SharedAngular/Templates/datePicker.html"
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="{{ name }}_datePicker" name="{{ name }}_datePicker" class="form-control" max-mode="maxMode" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="bindingProperty" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" ng-required="isRequired" close-text="Close" is-open="opened" ng-init="opened=false" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="opened=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="form.{{ name }}_datePicker.$invalid && form.{{ name }}_datePicker.$dirty" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign form-control-feedback datepicker-error-icon"></span>
</p>
```

Using the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <custom-date-picker name="'somePrefix'" form="myForm" ng-model="ctrl.Date" max-mode="'month'" max-date="ctrl.currentDate" format="'yyyy/MM/dd'" is-required="true"></custom-date-picker>
</div>
```